# Fails to load image from UIImagePickerController on next ViewController after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to load a picture selected on `UIImagePickerController` on the next view controller. i did some search on similar threads and found a few that helped me set it up, but the image does not really get 'transfered' to the next view controller.

this is my code for the didFinishPickingImage and prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
                              didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    self.imageChosen = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Edit" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Edit"]){
    EditViewController *editViewController = 
                       (EditViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    editViewController.imageView.image = self.imageChosen;
}
```

I am getting the segue running to the `EditViewController`, but the imageView there doesnt load the picture. I guess the assignment is wrong somehow but I fail to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to set image to `EditViewController` `UIImageView` it doesn't not exist because `EditViewController` not loaded yet. Instead of setting image to `UIImageView` directly create an instance variable in `EditViewController` that will hold image. And than assign this image to `UIImageView` in `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Edit"]){
    EditViewController *editViewController = 
                   (EditViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    editViewController.image = self.imageChosen;
}

//EditViewController.h
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
...

//EditViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    ...
}
```